# Carousel Loop only duplicating

Tags: wp-query, loop

I have problem with looping and WP_Query. Any idea how i can implement the multiple carouselitems please check what html output should be in html

So basically one of my goal is each div have a pages

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3"></div>
```

should have get all pages from parents which is "Destinations".

So i have an class CarouselItem active. (Actually this is only a slider style for changing the contents purposes).

And here the previous what html code should be in wordpress i mean the output in html format.

```
<section class="carouselItem active">
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
        <span>
          <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-12">
          <-- thumbnail -->
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-12">
          <-- content -->
          </div>
        </span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
        <span>
          <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-12">
          <-- thumbnail -->
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-12">
          <-- content -->
          </div>
        </span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
        <span>
          <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-12">
          <-- thumbnail -->
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-12">
          <-- content -->
          </div>
        </span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
        <span>
          <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-12">
          <-- thumbnail -->
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-12">
          <-- content -->
          </div>
        </span>
      </div>
</section>

<section class="carouselItem"></section>
<section class="carouselItem"></section>
```

And here what i do with wordpress. Yes i'm a little bit new with wordpress.

Here what i do i use post_per_page to 4, post_type to pages since i want to query all pages under destinations. And post_parent to a variable of $destination with ->ID

```
 <?php 
  $destination = get_page_by_title( 'Destinations');
  // WP_Query arguments
  $args = array (
    'post_parent'            => $destination->ID,
    'post_type'              => 'page',
    'posts_per_page'         => '4',
  );

  // The Query
  $query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>  
<section class="carouselItem active">
    <?php 
        if($query-> have_posts()): while($query->have_posts()): $query->the_post(); 
        $location = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Location', $single = true);
    ?>  
     <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
        <span>
          <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-12">
            <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) : // Check if thumbnail exists ?>
              <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail('homepage'); // Declare pixel size you need inside the array ?>
              </a>
            <?php else :?>
                <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/images/others/placeholder2.jpg" alt="">
            <?php endif; ?>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-12">
            <h5><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h5>
            <small><?php echo $location; ?> </small>
            <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
          </div>
        </span>
      </div>  
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>   
</section>
```

Result on me is are they only loop the content and the carouselItem is not duplicating for another post

[image: check this images so here what i want to do instead of of the working.]

Thank you for help. i'm very new with WP_Query.

Update after the update for diego:
The carousel is now working but the pages seems only same. like this one

slider 1 = A A A A
slider 2 = B B B B
slider 3 = C C C C
slider 4 = D D D D

instead of
slider 1 = A B C D
slider 2 = E F G H
slider 3 = I J K L

Answer (score 1):

You should reset the query after your active slider.
So place this code after your first loop (after endwhile; endif; ):

```
//Reset Query
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Also try setting the paged atribute:

```
$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
// WP_Query arguments
$args = array (
    'post_parent'            => $destination->ID,
    'post_type'              => 'page',
    'posts_per_page'         => '4',
    'paged'                  => $paged,
);
```

Hope that helps,
Cheers

Comment: Thank you but it's not work yeah i already read the codex and i already put the wp_reset_postdata(); but still not working.

Comment: Can you paste the rest of the html/php code? you only pasted the code for the first slider...

Comment: i only have 1 slider and that from above i'm not sure if i'm going right or not.

Comment: please see the edited answer with the "paged" atribute.

Comment: Now it working the carousel part but the post seems duplicating see my edited topic. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What about trying a different approach using [get_pages()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages) ?

```
  $destination = get_page_by_title( 'Destinations');
  $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
  $num_pages_per_page = 4;

  $args = array(
    'sort_order' => 'ASC',
    'child_of' => $destination->ID,
    'number' => $num_pages_per_page,
    'offset' => ( $paged - 1 ) * $num_pages_per_page,
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'post_status' => 'publish'
    ); 
    $pages = get_pages($args);
```

This will get an array with your pages...
On page 2 you will get 5,6,7,8 and so on...

Hope that solves your problem,

Comment: still not working. Anyway thanks you for the help i think i need to do a 2 loops one is for the carousel item and one for the pages inside the carousel.

Answer (score -2):

before the slider

```
//<?php $i = 0; ?>
<section class="carouselItem <?php if($i == 0 ) : echo "active"; ?>">

//start loop here

<section class="carouselItem <?php if($i == 0 ) : echo "active"; ?>">

 </section>
 //$i++; end loop
```

Hope this will solve your problem